# Purpose For Madison's Nightmare in Heavy Rain?

Tags: heavy-rain

Is there a reason why Madison, in her first sequence in Heavy Rain, has a nightmare about being attacked by four men breaking into her apartment? I don't remember it ever getting explained as the game goes on. It certainly is a striking scene if only because she gets thrown on a bed (which would imply a motivation of sexual assault) and replaying the game has me wondering about it.

Anyone have any idea as to why she has this nightmare and why it was never mentioned again?

Comment: Sadly, we don't get to know her as well as the other characters. It seemed to *me* to just be motive for getting her out of her apartment and into the plot.

Answer (score 2):

We discover that Madison suffers from insomnia early in the game, and she can only sleep in motels. As @SevenSidedDie said, this is probably just to inform you why she's in room 209 of a motel and conveniently able (or hideously incapable) to take care of (and meet) Ethan. It may also be a scenario to set up one of the endings,  [Square One.](http://heavyrain.wikia.com/wiki/Epilogue_-_Square_One)

Answer (score 2):

It's relevant that there were several scenes deleted from the game. One of them introduced Madison as a war journalist, and her nightmares are apparently a result of trauma during the war.

Source (one of many): http://www.engadget.com/2010/11/08/heavy-rains-deleted-scenes-exposed-reveal-supernatural-conne/

As other scenes in the game were also removed but plot points that resulted from them (such as

> why Ethan ends up with an origami figure whenever the killer gets a new victim

) were left in and left unexplained, I think the deleted scene is the best explanation you can get.